# Temporary failure in name resolution

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I am using AWS ebs , rds, s3 , cloudwatch but on cloudwatch it is continuously pinging in almost 2 minutes this warning:

2018-05-30 6:59:22 47603113539328 [Warning] IP address '85.93.20.90' could not be resolved: Temporary failure in name resolution

If anybody is aware of this , let me know .

Thanks

Comment: What exactly is giving this error?

Comment: Your question does not provide enough detail. Please edit your question and add details to explain what you are trying to achieve, what is happening and what you'd like to happen. For example, what does "on cloudwatch it is continuously pinging" mean?

Comment: "2018-05-30 6:59:22 47603113539328 [Warning] IP address '85.93.20.90' could not be resolved: Temporary failure in name resolution"  cloudwatch pinging this warning